# Images not having a fixed width

Tags: html, css

I'm making a responsive website and, when I reduce the screen size, the images follow along and they are reduced too. How do I get a fixed width here? I've changed from rem to px trying to solve it but it didn't.

```
<section class="section-3">
        <div class="container-text">
            <h2>Our Global Campus</h2>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        </div><!--container-text-->

        <div class="box-images">
            <div class="single-image"></div>
            <div class="single-image"></div>
            <div class="single-image"></div>
        </div><!--box-images-->

    </section><!--section-3-->
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.section-3{
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}


.box-images{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 800px;
    padding: 0 368px;
    
}

.single-image{
    width: 699px;
    height: 624px;
    margin: 0 32px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: you can use `max-width` here?

Comment: Are the actual images important, or just the `<div>` containers? It might help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `flex: 1 0 auto;` to your children DIVs. Implementing this will allow for the DIVs (images) to maintain their fixed widths.

**CSS**

```
.box-images {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 0 368px;
}
.box-images .single-image {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 699px;
  height: 624px;
  margin: 0 32px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```